# SQL Query finding field with multiple rows

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to write a query that queries table Z_INSUR.  I want to find all instances where the same EMP has more than 1 row where the INSUR_TYPE is M.  I want to see all of the EMPs that do this, which is why I added the UNIQUE part to the query.  Below is what I've tried so far but it doesn't work.  Can someone help me with this?  I'm using ORacle

```
select UNIQUE(EMP) from Z_INSUR where COUNT(INSUR_TYPE = 'M') > 1;
```

Comment: `unique` (or `distinct`) is ***NOT*** a function. Writing `select unique (emp)` is similar to writing `select (emp)` - the paranthesises don't serve any purpose.

Comment: @JoeEngle Your question is not clear enough, please consider my assumptions in my answer. (Writing this, because you thanked Fabien already. Under certain assumptions his answer may be wrong.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT EMP 
FROM Z_INSUR 
WHERE INSUR_TYPE = 'M'
GROUP BY EMP 
HAVING count(*) > 1;
```

Answer (score 3):

Since you didn't specify, I am going to assume you're using SQL Server.

`select emp from z_insur where insur_type = 'm' group by emp having count(emp) > 1`

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming you want each EMP that has multiple rows in the same table but not necessarily more than one have a row with `INSUR_TYPE = 'M'`.

If you want to see EMPs that have multiple rows where `INSUR_TYPE = 'M'` is true, it's better to go with Fabien's solution. If not, his is wrong, please consider that.

```
SELECT EMP 
FROM Z_INSUR 
GROUP BY EMP 
HAVING SUM(CASE WHEN INSUR_TYPE = 'M' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 1;
```